# Flexbox with ul list

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to use flexbox to build 2x2 grid with my list. My code is as follows:

```
<ul class="cont">
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.cont { display: flex; }
.cont li { width: 50%; }
```

Unfortunately, it aligns four of my `li` in a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the flexible box row and give the items `flex-basis: 50%` or `width: 50%`

```css
.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap; /* Shorthand for flex-direction: row and flex-wrap: wrap */
}
.cont li {
  flex-basis: 50%; /* or width: 50% */
}
```

```html
<ul class="cont">
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

`flex-wrap: wrap` let's flex know it's allowed to wrap. It's default argument when undefined is `nowrap`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set the flex properties of the `li` *and* make sur eyou tell the parent to wrap when required.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.cont li {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="cont">
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use flex-direction.

```
.cont {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column; // or row depending on which way you want it to flow
}
```